# Upperbound of the ratio of column sums of an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $X_{n \times n}$ is a positive integer matrix where $n\geq 2$. The element in the $i_{th}$ row and $j_{th}$ column of the matrix $X$ is defined as $x_{i,j}$. Now, consider

$S_{j,j+1}=argmax_{i}\{x_{i,j}+x_{i,j+1}\}$

$sum1=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}S_{j,j+1}$

and

$sum2=argmax_{i}\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{i,j}$}

If the ratio of $sum1$ and $sum2$ is defined by $R=\frac{sum1}{sum2}$, what is the upperbound of $R$?

---

**EXAMPLE:**

$$X_{3 \times 3}=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 3\\ 
2 & 5 & 2\\ 
4 & 6 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$S_{1,2}=4+6=10$ because the sum of 1st and 2nd element is maximum for the 3rd row. So, in this case $i=3$

Similarly, $S_{2,3}=5+2=6+1=7$. In this case 2nd and 3rd element is maximum for both 2nd and 3rd row (both are 7). So, $i=2$ or $i=3$, both are true.

$sum1=10+7=17$

Now, in order to compute $sum2$, we need to find out for which row, the column sum is maximum. For the 1st row, colum sum is $4+1+3=8$, for the 2nd row column sum is $2+5+2=9$ and for the 3rd row column sum is $4+6+1=11$. So, $sum2=11$ and $i=3$.

We can compute the ratio $R=\frac{sum1}{sum2}=\frac{17}{11}=1.545$

Comment: what does argmax mean?

Comment: $argmax_i$ mean the value of $i$ or row number in this case for which the expression inside the curly brace is maximum.

Comment: maybe you had better type in a 2 by 2 example (with actual numbers, not symbols in the matrix), where your quantities have few choices, and maybe a 3 by 3 example

Comment: Ok, I am going to put an example here for a 3 by 3 matrix.

Comment: Here is an argument for the supremum - WLOG let the maximum be $k$.  To maximize $S_{j, j+1}$, we set $x_{i,j} = x_{i,j+1}=2k$, so $S_{j,j+1}=2k$.  To keep sum$_2$ lowest, we need all other entries $1$, so $R_{\max, k} = 2(n-1)k/(n+2k-2) = 2(n-1) /(2+\frac{n-2}k)$ which gets its supremum as $k \to \infty$ as $(n-1)$.

Comment: The diagonal and offset entries are $k$ above, not $2k$ which is a typo.

Comment: I think this is correct.